# How to force entity translations to load in a certain language with user_view() or entity_view()

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

I have a custom view mode that uses a template to print out user profiles.

I am saving the HTML from this view mode in the Solr search index using Search API Solr.

In `user--my-view-mode.tpl.php`, I print out the various fields of the user profile, including one that is a *taxonomy term* that has been translated by the **Entity Reference** and **Title** modules:

```
  $agegroup = $user_profile['field_acc_age_group'][1]['#markup'];
```

In the Search API callback, I call this view mode like this:

```
$render = user_view($item, 'my-view-mode', 'ja');
```

Here's the problem-- the profile is rendered in Japanese except the taxonomy term, which has been translated by Entity Reference/Title.

When I make a view that shows output of *Rendered User* and set the view mode to *my-view-mode*, and access the view with a user who has the language set to Japanese, then the taxonomy term is translated correctly.

So how do I get `user_view()` or `entity_view()` to show translated entity translations along with the rest of the translated output?

Answer (score 0):

So one workaround is to force it manually like this:

```
$agegroup = $user_profile['field_acc_age_group']['#items'][1]['taxonomy_term']->name_field[$lang][0]['value'];
```